# What is /bin/dash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I thought `/bin/sh` was a symlink to my shell of choice. I've always used `bash`, so I assumed that `/bin/sh` would point to `/bin/bash`. It turns out, though, that it points to `/bin/dash`.

It gets funnier. I start `dash` and do `echo $SHELL` and it prints `/bin/bash` (so they're basically the same?). However, the man page of `dash` is completely different from the man page of `bash` (so they're *not* the same?).

Comment: @wzzrd, Is this question linux-specific?

Comment: sigh, I can't upvote all of these nice answers, since I need 15 rep. I feel handicapped as I have 18k on stackoverflow :-/

Comment: mmm dash.. what about /bin/crash (for gdb fans), /bin/slash (an austerity program), /bin/mash (hard times in Korea), /bin/sash (for cheerleaders), /bin/thrash (hard on your HDD), /bin/flash (but only if you encrypt your data), /bin/stash (good luck finding it later), /bin/cash (you're always in-the-money), /bin/pash (romancing the PC), /bin/gash (aaargggh!).

Comment: @PP Dash is short for Debian Almquist Shell. And your forgetting /bin/clash (for all your dependency problems). @aioobe, as far as I know, Dash is only used in Linux, but there is nothing stopping you from building it on some *BSD. But I can remove the 'linux' tag again. No problem.

Comment: @PP - I'd read /bin/thrash for Metal music fans, and /bin/slash for fans of 80's rock band lead guitarists...  :-P

Comment: The reason `echo $SHELL` prints `/bin/bash` is because that variable is set for the default shell that starts when you login rather than the current shell you're running. Start ksh or zsh from a Bash prompt and `echo $SHELL` will still say `/bin/bash`. Use `ps` to see what's currently running.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: Nice, I didn't know that. I had assumed it was a flaw in / feature missing from dash.

Comment: Your shell of choice is stored in the account database (`/etc/passwd`). `/bin/sh` always points to Bourne Shell (or compatible).

Comment: Wait, what?  To find your currently executing shell you should not need to use ps, I use do `echo $0`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Debian and Ubuntu switched to dash (iirc) because of a couple of things. First of all, Bash has become big over the years. In fact, the `/bin/bash` binary on my Ubuntu 8.04 system is almost ten times (!) as big as `/bin/dash`. Now, that does not matter much for day to day shell use, but it does matter in the following situations:

- Dash is much smaller and thus loads faster, which is a boon for init-scripts. If you have to start a lot of them, loading Dash instead of Bash each time, speeds things up considerably.
- Because of the smaller size of Dash, Debian and Ubuntu are able to shave off a pretty big chunk of the size of their initrd, leaving more room for other stuff (and again, speeding things up).

The downside of using Dash instead of Bash for scripting, is that a lot of people use syntactical niceties only Bash has, the so-called *Bashisms*. Examples of Bashisms are substrings, like this:

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
a=1234567890
echo ${a}
1234567890
echo ${a:3}
4567890
echo ${a:3:1}
4
```

And this:

```
echo ${a#123}
4567890
```

Dash, on the other hand mainly aims to be POSIX compliant (and no more than that), will give you a *Bad substition* error if you try this:

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/dash 
# actually, it will read /bin/bash above, because if you just run dash
# it will not set the $SHELL variable :)
a=1234567890
echo ${a}
1234567890
echo ${a:3}
dash: Bad substitution
```

This will matter if you use `/bin/sh` (and therefore `dash`) as the interpreter for your shellscripts and use Bashisms in them. Debian and Ubuntu have nice wiki pages about Bashisms and why they are bad in shellscripts in general and init-scripts in particular. Therefore, you should consciously choose whether you need `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` as the interpreter for your script.

Dash is not supposed to be used as the default shell on your systems. Just use Bash for that. For portability of your scripts, you can use Dash as the interpreter to increase the odds the scripts will run on other Linux flavors and Unixes.

Comment: If you write scripts with Bashisms, please specify `/bin/bash`; many non-Linux systems have actual `sh` shells which aren't even close to compatible with `bash`.

Comment: `echo ${a#123}` is not a bashism, it's part of the POSIX Parameter expansion spec. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html

You just don't get the more advanced sed style Bash ones, The posix ones are substring style + simple expansion characters.  Meaning, POSIX also allows `echo ${a#*6}`

Answer (score 4):

Take a look here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh maybe It will help.

Answer (score 1):

dash is a lightweight bash replacement, im assuming you use ubuntu which changed to it a few years ago.

Its not overly good though, imho.
http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=45116

Answer (score 0):

Since not all shells set `$SHELL` when run, you find out your current shell with:

```
echo $0
```

If it gives an error, it's csh, otherwise it's the `argv[0]` you were invoked with, which is typically the shell, perhaps with a leading `-` hyphen, to indicate that it's a login shell.

This isn't *guaranteed*, since `argv[0]` is under the control of the invoking process, but it is in practice the most reliable approach.